# Truncate part of an existing field value to a new field using painless?

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

I'm having a timestamp field which has a value something like this , where pretty much all the values would be in the same format:

`January 1st 2017, 05:29:59.000`

What I need is to trim part of the above which should look:

`January 1st 2017`

So what I wanted to know is whether is it possible to do the above using `painless` scripting within `Kibana` itself? Something like assign the trimmed value to a new scripted field? I wanted to do it within `Kibana` , since I just wanted to show only the shorter format of the date in the graph.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a `painless` scripted field, using the `moment.js` date formatting. But then I had to change the `Popularity` to 0 since having it as 1 didn't allow me to access the scripted field in the graph. Making it 0 worked. This is how my scripted_field look like:

[image]